ID Christmas horror movie: skinny Santas feeding children to giant Santa
This movie was in color and was released in the late 90s to early 2000s, and had a very dark feeling to it.  It featured a small army of skinny Santa-like creatures that stole 'naughty' children and fed them to a single giant Santa-like creature. At some point they captured one of the skinny Santa minions, and somehow used it to find the main Santa.
More details:
I saw it on TV in America, it was in English although I'm unsure where the setting was... in the mountains somewhere? No other scenes, it's been a long time.... There was a little boy as one of the characters who was about to be captured.

Hi. Do you remember the country\language? Any other characters or scenes? Where did you see it?

I saw it on TV in America, it was in English although I'm unsure where the setting was...in the mountains somewhere?  No other scenes, it's been a long time....there was a little boy as one of the characters who was about to be captured

Thanks. Added &posted a possible match (though it's from 2010 and Finnish).

Sounds very much like the plot of Rare Exports from 2010.

On Christmas Eve in Finland, Santa Claus is unearthed in an archaeological dig. Soon after, children start disappearing, leading a boy and his father to capture Santa and, with the help of fellow hunters, they look to sell him back to the corporation that sponsored the dig. And then there's Santa's elves, who are determined to free their leader...

The 'elves' really look like skinny Santas and 'Santa' is actually Krampus, a huge horned creature. Here's the trailer:



